# Set UILabel constraints depending on other label text

Tags: ios, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have a UITableViewCell with 2 labels (1)for the name of person (2)for a note about him.
I need to layout the labels one above the other with VFL and that works fine.

**BUT -** 
if the note is empty I want the name label to vertically center in the cell.

Do I need to add other constrain or is there any other way to set this condition in VFL ?

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout doesn't provide format options fitting your case. If the constraints are set up in IB, then when the label is empty you have to remove them programmatically and add new constraints.

Also, please remember that cells are probably being reused.